# Trying to find if there is a relationship between convictions for corruption and changes in electoral districts after a census

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis

I have a small request for help with some tests of a data set I am working with for my thesis.

I am attempting to see if there is a relationship between the years before during and after a census (thus a change in districts) and the number of convictions for corruption.

I have graphed the data and used the students T test and do not see anything ( I could be mistaken of course) but I remembered from class that the professor said that there were other ways to test data that were not in the course I took this time last year. 
[image: screen shot from the data set]
this is a screen shot of the data - it shows state and the number of convictions by year for 35 years.
[image: graph of convictions]
[image: graph of states identified as having districts that do not meet criteria for compactness]

Above are graphs of the data I have already made. The graph for 'Compactness' was based on states that were identified as having unusually non-compact districts.

I am not sure what tools to use in this case, I am attempting to use R but am a neophyte to say the least

Comment: You have multiple count time series, so could look for changepoints in the series.

Comment: I did that with the graphs but cannot discern a pattern...I thought there might be another way I have not been made aware of.